# H2 DB CSVREAD does not translate line breaks

Tags: csv, h2

I would like to use H2 database embedded in my application to create an in-memory database, populated by a CSV file. So I have used the CSVREAD function.

All is working well except one pesky problem, which is that it doesn't seem to recognize line breaks. It translates `\n` literally as the two characters `\` and `n`.

The docs say that the default escape character is quotation mark but if I try to use the quotation mark to escape anything else besides another quotation mark, it simply ends the record there.

Is it possible to put text with line breaks into a CSV file and have H2's CSVREAD interpret it correctly somehow? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much experimentation, I found that literally putting returns into the middle of the text is interpreted correctly.

e.g. if you want a record with multiple lines, try this in your csv:

```
"column 1", "column 2", "column 3 multi-line

still part of column 3

yet still pat of column 3"
```